# Angular Bind a value to Directive parameter

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I'm building a directive which changes a button's text while a condition remains true. For example while saving a from, until it is being processed, the text of the submit button should change to `Saving...` and as the form submission finished, it should revert back to its original text.

Here is a what I'm trying:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[LoadingText]'
})
export class LoadingTextDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('loadingTextValue') text: string;
  @Input('loadingTextWhen') condition: boolean;

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.text && this.condition) {
        this.elem.nativeElement.innerText = this.text;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I'm using it:

```
<button LoadingText loadingTextValue="Hold on! Saving..." [loadingTextWhen]="saving" type="button" (click)="onSave()">Save
                            </button>

saving: boolean = false;
```

I change `saving` to true as onSave() function is called and false as it is finished.

How can I bind my directive condition Input to reflect according to the changes on `saving`.?

Comment: Ref: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook by Angular to get the changes in your `@Input` binding.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[LoadingText]'
})
export class LoadingTextDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('loadingTextValue') text: string;
  @Input('loadingTextWhen') condition: boolean;

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.text) {
      if (this.condition) {
        this.elem.nativeElement.innerText = this.text;
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log(changes.condition.currentValue);
    this.condition = changes.condition.currentValue;
    if (this.text) {
      if (this.condition) {
        this.elem.nativeElement.innerText = this.text;
      }
      else {
        this.elem.nativeElement.innerText = 'Save'
      }
    }
    // you will get changes in `@input` text here and made changes accordingly
  }
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/button-loading-using-directive?file=src/app/loading.ts)

Comment: `implements OnInit, OnChanges` . I know it is JavaScript at end of the day. It does not matter. But it is recommended in Angular Coding Style Guide. :)

Comment: @RitwickDey, eagle eye !! Thanks dude for pointing me out , Answer Updated !!

Comment: In this case, ngOnChanges is called before ngOnInit. I'm getting the initial value of the element in ngOninit but it gives undefined.

Comment: @Subhan , `ngOnChanges` is always called before `ngOnInit`, So you can call some common method form both cycle hooks, if needed

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use subject variable:

in your component HTML:

```
<label [loadingTextValue]="loadValue"></label>
```

in your component TS:

```
loadValue = new Subject();

changeValue() {
   this.loadValue.next('Your_Value');
}
```

in directive:

```
@Input('loadingTextValue') text: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribe = this.text
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.el.nativeElement.innerText = value;
      })
  }
```